# MongoDB: create dynamic view from expanding set of collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a database of collections, and I'm taking a snapshot of a collection at a point of time as the data is constantly changing, but I need to create repeatable processes hence the snapshot. I'm doing this by copying the main collection at a point in time, and renaming it .g. 'Captures20220123'.

I need to be able to query the entire list across all collections, e.g. 'Captures', 'Captures20220123', 'Captures20220122' etc.

Is it possible to create a view in MongoDB which aggregates data from all collections which have the name 'Captures*'?

I'm aware I can query the collection names client side, and dynamically build a query that way, but wondered if it's possible in a view as I have several different clients in different languages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you can do it like this:

```
var pipeline = []
firstCol = db.getSiblingDB('config').collections.findOne({_id: /Captures/ }).sort( {_id: 1} ) 
db.getSiblingDB('config').collections.find({_id: /Captures/ }).sort( {_id: 1} ).skip(1).forEach( ( col ) => {
   pipeline.push({ $unionWith: col._id })
})
db.createView("AllCaptures", firstCol , pipeline)
```

Or course, you would have to run this procedure every day when a new collection is created. Test it carefully, the performance might a horrible. I assume in the end you will query the collections one by one.

BTW, instead of "copy and rename" the collection, consider just to rename it. If you try to insert data into a collection which does not exist, then MongoDB creates a new collection automatically. You may only have to create some indexes on the new collection.

Comment: Thanks! Running this for every new collection could be problematic as forgetting could be disastrous (btw I simplified my question and ended up implying there would be one new collection per day, but that's not the case).